# MySQL - Find strings

Tags: mysql, string, pattern-matching

is there a short way to select entries by finding a specific pattern?

I have a column called "keyword" in my table "data" and yes, I find some entries but not all by executing the following query:

```
SELECT ca.userid_click, ca.keyword 
FROM data ca WHERE 
ca.date > '2016-05-01'
AND (ca.keyword LIKE '%[AAID]%_%[IDFA]%')
GROUP BY ca.userid_click, ca.keyword;
```

Sadly I have some missing entries and I have no glue how I can get them.

Common for all wanted entries is a pattern like

```
47ba96a8-cafa-4ce1-ab23-fa4a5df5a381
```

or

```
b839927c-cc05-4235-92e0-86763472700f
```

So **8 characters-4 characters-4 characters-4 characters-12 characters** binded with an "**-**". The problem is sometimes this substring is in the beginning, sometimes in the middle or the end of my string.

Is there a smart way to extract those entries? I tried several approaches but I guess there is a way to extract all.

Comment: GROUP BY has no business being in a query such as this.

Comment: Do hyphens appear else where in the string?

Comment: try using Regular Expression http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Comment: regex will work fine for you

Comment: @Strawberry: Yes... there are hyphens in the string!

Comment: SELECT 
ca.userid_click, ca.keyword 
FROM data ca 
WHERE 
ca.keyword REGEXP '[*]{8}-[*]{4}-[*]{4}-[*]{4}-[*]{12}';